# List files scala emr hdfs (csv file missing)

Tags: scala, csv, hadoop, amazon-emr

I am trying to list all the files in a directory on emr hdfs via the following method:

```
val directory = new File(directoryPath)
val fileStatusListIterator: RemoteIterator[LocatedFileStatus] = FileUtils.fs.listFiles(new Path(directoryPath), true)
while (fileStatusListIterator.hasNext) {
  val fileStatus = fileStatusListIterator.next
  if (fileStatus.isFile) {
    log.info(s"Iterator File Path: ${fileStatus.getPath}")
  }
}
```

my problem: it is listing everything except csv files.

Comment: Are you sure those "csv files" aren't actually _directories_? If they were created by some distributed-processing engine (MapReduce/Spark) they might be directories with "part" files inside them, and your code skips directories.

Comment: I removed the condition, and the same result no CSV files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason. because I was downloading this csv file exactly before the listing. Which mean the file could not make it on time to be catches from the iterator. Therefore, I have to use:

```
Future.Await(Downloading,Duration.Inf)
```

So it will be forced to wait till the downloading is finished then it will continue.